# How to draw line segments made of different colors with correct joins?

Tags: c#, winforms, gdi+

I use the following code to draw multiple lines :

```
using (var path = new GraphicsPath())
{           
    foreach (var linesByColor in lines.GroupByAdjacent(x => x.Color))
    {           
        path.Reset();       
        foreach (var lines in linesByColor)
        {
            path.AddLine(...);
        }
    
        using (var pen = new Pen(linesByColor.Key))
        {
            g.DrawPath(pen, path);
        }
    }           
}
```

Here is the result (please ignore the black border) :

[image]

The issue occurs between red and green paths (at the join).
It make sense since it's two different paths.
Here is what I want :

[image]

Is there a way to achieve this easily ?
One possibility would be to not draw lines but shapes, taking care of the joins. That's probably not trivial.

Comment: No, this is exactly as non-trivial as you assumed.  You have to use two paths, with the chamfer part of the path.

Comment: You could also add a [LineCap](http://www.java2s.com/Code/VB/2D/LineCapsDemo.htm).

Comment: It seems you use a centered pen alignment. Did you try [other](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.pen.alignment) alignments?

Comment: [Pen.CustomLineCap](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.drawing2d.customlinecap)